# Using fullcalendar.io with Slim and AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, json, fullcalendar, slim

Using the slim framework, I have created an route that selects a record from the database and encodes it into json and renders this into a view.

```
<?php
    $app->get('/calendar/json', function() use ($app) {

        $events = $app->Calendar->all();

        $events = json_encode($events);

        $app->render('calendar/json.json', array(

            "events" => $events     

        ));

    })->name('calendar.json');

?>
```

Which shows this result

```
 [{"id":"1","title":"Test Event","start":"2015-07-01"},{"id":"2","title":"Test Event 2","start":"2015-07-09"}]
```

Using the [jQuery full calendar library](http://fullcalendar.io/), I want to pull this data into the calendar using ajax.

Following the example off their site using an external Json file the data appears on the calandar.

```
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
      },
     editable: true,
     eventLimit: true,
     events: {
        url: "data.json",
        }
    });
```

If I replicate this but change the URL parameter to access my view the data is not displayed however it is formatted in the same way.

```
 var url = "{{ urlFor('calendar.json') }}";     

 url: url,
```

This is what I have replaced in the jQuery to access the view, is this the correct way to access the view or will the view not render as I am not directly on the page for the view.

Comment: Did the answer fix your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First:**

Your Json can't be valid Json, because you don't set the Content-Type - so i think it will be `text/html` (or something) instead of `application/json`.

So set that and return the Json directly as Response-body:

```php
$app->response()->header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
$app->response()->setBody($events);
```

Also you don't need an empty view.

**Second:**

In the [docs](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/) there is a basic example without some custom params that "say" that you can pass the url directly as `events`.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: '/myfeed.php'
});
```